# Speeding up Eclipse when editing JS/JSP files

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp, editing, eclipse-mars

I’m using STS (a derivative of Eclipse Mars):

```
Spring Tool Suite
Version: 3.7.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201506290652
Platform: Eclipse Mars (4.5.0)
```

When I open a JSP or JS file in my editor (by right clicking the name of the file from the package explorer), Eclipse/STS eventually hangs when I start editing the file,  It will then spit out messages like so

```
Unhandled event loop exception
GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Before I start throwing memory at the problem, I wanted to see if there was any unnecessary plugins or other things I can turn off to speed up simple text editing of these types of files.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that maybe can help you (altough I'm afraid it is some bug in your version of STS):

- Have you tried to turn off JSP validation? Look at the project properties > validation > HTML syntax, JSP syntax.
- You can monitor the memory status by toggling on the checkbox Window > Preferences > General > Show heap status. From then on, you will see at the bottom of the main window a single graph of the heap, plus a button to call the GC.